# Apply a vertical rule beside graphics within Algorithm floats

Tags: graphics, algorithms, rules

### Background

Using LyX to write a book. The source code listings shown in the book are graphics. The graphics should have a vertical rule beside them. But only graphics that are embedded within an Algorithm float. The code for the float resembles:

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\includegraphics{source/sql/query-formatted.sql.png}

\caption{\label{alg:Query-with-Formatting}Query with Formatting}

\end{algorithm}
```

There are scores of these example source code snippets, with more to come. Adding code to each one, manually, is undesirable.

### Problem

Listing 1.1 in the following figure shows the placement character `[H]` nestled between the vertical rule and the graphic:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1i4k.png

The preamble used:

```
% Determine if the image is too wide for the page.
\makeatletter
\def\ScaleIfNeeded{%
  \ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth
    \linewidth
  \else
    \Gin@nat@width
  \fi
}
\makeatother

% Resize figures that are too wide for the page.
\let\oldincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{%
  \oldincludegraphics[width=\ScaleIfNeeded]{#2}
  \graphicsalignment
}

% Do not centre graphics within Algorithm floats.    
\expandafter\def\expandafter\algorithm\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\graphicsalignment\expandafter\relax
  \algorithm
  \vrule width 1em
}

\let\graphicsalignment\centering
```

### Question

How do you eliminate the `[H]` argument so that the `\vrule` appears flush with the graphic, and placed "Here definitely"? (I have managed to do this in other ways, but then the graphics are no longer "`H`ere definitely.")

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do here is change

```
\expandafter\def\expandafter\algorithm\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\graphicsalignment\expandafter\relax
  \algorithm
  \vrule width 1em
}
```

to

```
\let\oldalgorithm\algorithm
\let\endoldalgorithm\endalgorithm
\renewenvironment{algorithm}[1][htbp]{
        \let\graphicsalignment\relax
        \oldalgorithm[#1]
                \vrule width1em
                \kern1em
}{%
        \endoldalgorithm
}
```

This only works for graphics because TeX treats them as a single box. For a more normal usage of `algorithm` which contains an `algorithmic` environment, the `coderule` environment from the previous question would be more suitable.

Comment: Thank you. Almost works. The `[H]` parameter is gone, but the vertical space it imposed remains. (That is, there is space between the image and `\vrule`.)

Comment: Caused by `width1em` rather than `width 1em`? Or caused by `\kern1em`. I changed the first and removed the second. It works now, thank you.

Comment: @Dave: The space was from the `\kern1em`.

Comment: Sadly, I had to shelve the idea of a LaTeX-based `\vrule` altogether, as it pushes the longer listings into the page margins.

Comment: @Dave: You could put the rule in the margin instead.